# Is Caffe::Net<Dtype> Multithread-safe?

Tags: c++, caffe

Is Caffe::Net multithread-safe?  Can you have several threads each with its own Caffe::Net in test mode?

It appears to me, looking at the code, that Caffe assumes only one instance of Net which launches multiple threads to access multiple GPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the [Github/BVLC/Github repo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4745), Fabian Tschopp, BVLC member, states that Caffe is multithread-safe if each thread instantiates its own network and set of blobs but that each network and its set of blobs should only be used on one thread.